# Parse Unity Facebook 400 Bad Request

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, parse-platform, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am using the Facebook SDK and Parse plugin. I can sucessfully login with Parse and Facebook independently. When I try to 'sign up' for parse using my Facebook access token I get a 400 bad request.

I believe my parse.com account is setup correctly (I have augmented the authentication section with my application ID(s) and secret(s) (for main app and test app).

Here is my code.

```
        // FB Init and Login here. It works.

        var logInTask = ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync(FB.UserId, FB.AccessToken, DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1));

        while (!logInTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            yield return 1;
        }

        if (logInTask.IsCanceled || logInTask.IsFaulted)
        {
            var error = logInTask.Exception as AggregateException;
            foreach (var e in error.InnerExceptions)
            {
                // Bad Request Here
                Debug.LogError(e);

            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong, how can I resolve this ?

Comment: Try debugging the result for more information. Try putting in a breakpoint before printing the error, and looking at what it's saying. Might be clearer than a simple 400 Error

Comment: I have breakpoints in place. What am I looking for exactly ?

Comment: Parse and FB compatibility is currently broken. The bug is here https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/641349069282576/ Avoid using FB users for now and hope they fix it. Make sure you "follow" the thread over on the FB dev page.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue here is that you're passing in a DateTime object for token expiration, when you should be passing in the expires_at value that came back with your Facebook login.  I believe this is an integer.